# CSV File upload delay on file request from Angular to Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, csv, file-upload

We doing csv file upload from Angular to Spring boot 2.x app, which contains around 1 million records, the 1 million records is processing in the server after a gap of more than 20 mins.
The csv file request to load file from Angular to Spring boot takes more time, it took around 20 mins to receive the file in the spring boot application.

Config in application.yml file

servlet:
multipart:
enabled: true
max-file-size: 200MB
max-request-size: 200MB

Could you help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file from Angular. You can simply save the file in server/cloud and add an entry in a table and return table record to Angular application.

Then you can process the file using Spring Batch and update status in table once the process is success/failed.

Now from Angular application, with received table data every few seconds interval you can simply hit an another spring boot controller endpoint which returns the status of the process.